# For $\phi\in C^1(0,\infty)$ and $\phi > 0$, does $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\phi'(t)}{\phi(t)/t}$ exist?

Tags: limits

Suppose that $\phi\in C^1(0,\infty)$, $\phi>0$. Does the following limit exist? $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\phi'(t)}{\dfrac{\phi(t)}{t}}$$

I could not find a counter example and yet, I dont have any idea to prove it. We can also suppose (if necessary) that $t\phi(t)$ is strictly increasing and $t\phi(t)\to 0$ if $t\to 0$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counter-example: $\phi(t)=2+\sin(\log t)$.

Comment: @Tomás: You are welcome!